# Python webscraping beautiful soup list error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to download images from BGS borehole scans where there are more than one page e.g. http://scans.bgs.ac.uk/sobi_scans/boreholes/795279/images/10306199.html http://scans.bgs.ac.uk/sobi_scans/boreholes/18913699/images/18910430.html

I manage to download the first 2 pages of the first example but when I get to the last page I get this error. On this page the NextPage variable should be None as that tag is not there on the webpage. At this point I want to continue to the next location, I haven't added that yet but I have an excel list of URL's. The code is based on this https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/brentond/Documents/Python/Pdf BGS Scans.py", line 73, in 
NextPage = soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

## Download BGS borehole scans from excel list of URL's

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import webbrowser
import PyPDF2
import os
import openpyxl
import pdfkit
import requests
import bs4



# Define path of excel file
from requests import Response

path = r'C:\Users\brentond\Documents\TA2'

# Change directory to target location
os.chdir(path)

# Create workbook object
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('BGS Boreholes.xlsm')

# Create worksheet object
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Open')

# Assign URL to variable
StartURL = ws['A2'].value
URL = StartURL
NextURL = "NextURL"

# Assign BH ID to variable
Location = ws['B2'].value

while NextURL is not None:
    # Download URL
    res = requests.get(URL)  # type: Response
    res.raise_for_status()

    # Create beautiful soup object
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the URL of the borehole scan image.
    Scan = soup.select('#image_content img')

    # Check on HTML elements
    Address = soup.select('#image')
    AddressText = Address[0].get('src')
    print(AddressText)

    print()
    if Scan == []:
        print('Could not find scan image.')
    else:
        ScanUrl = Scan[0].get('src')
        # Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (ScanUrl))
        res = requests.get(ScanUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

        # Save the image to path
        PageNo = 0
        imageFile = open(os.path.join(path, Location) + "-Page" + str(PageNo) + ".png", 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    # Find URL for next page
    PageNo = PageNo + 1
    NextPage = soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')[0]
    if NextPage ==[]:
        continue
    else:
        print(NextPage)
        NextURL = NextPage.get('href')
        URL = NextURL
        print(NextURL)

print('Done.')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not there you cannot select its first element. You can try to verify the elements presence with `find` / `find_all` first or you can use `try`/`except` to account for the IndexError and modify your scripts behaviour in the error case.

Answer (score 1):

So because the anchor does not exist the `soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')` will always return an empty list. Therefore key zero will not exist hence the IndexError is raised.

The easiest thing it to change

```
    NextPage = soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')[0]
    if NextPage ==[]:
        continue
    else:
        print(NextPage)
        NextURL = NextPage.get('href')
```

to

```
    NextPage = soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')
    if not NextPage:
        continue
    else:
        NextPage = NextPage[0]
        print(NextPage)
        NextURL = NextPage.get('href')
```

Or

```
    NextPage = soup.select('a[title="Next page"]')
    if not NextPage:
        continue
    else:
        print(NextPage[0])
        NextURL = NextPage[0].get('href')
```

Depending on your personal preference